# Browser does not display PNG image

Tags: php, gd

**I want to use the GD libs, which seems installed but I can't use it.**

I look at my gd installation with

```
php_info();
```

It returns me this:
[image]

Then I tried this:

```
<pre>
<?php print_r(gd_info())?>
</pre>
```

Which returns this:

```
Array
(
    [GD Version] => bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
    [FreeType Support] => 1
    [FreeType Linkage] => with freetype
    [T1Lib Support] => 1
    [GIF Read Support] => 1
    [GIF Create Support] => 1
    [JPEG Support] => 1
    [PNG Support] => 1
    [WBMP Support] => 1
    [XPM Support] => 
    [XBM Support] => 1
    [JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support] => 
)
```

But when I try to make this:

[image]

Using that code:

```
<?php // content="text/plain; charset=utf-8"
$im =  imagecreatetruecolor ( 300, 200);
$black = imagecolorallocate ($im,  0, 0, 0);
$lightgray = imagecolorallocate ($im,  230, 230, 230);
$darkgreen = imagecolorallocate ($im,  80, 140, 80);
$white = imagecolorallocate ($im,  255, 255, 255);

imagefilledrectangle ($im,0,0,299,199 ,$lightgray);
imagerectangle ($im,0,0,299,199,$black);
imagefilledellipse ($im,150,100,210,110,$white);
imagefilledellipse ($im,150,100,200,100,$darkgreen);
header ("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng ($im);
?>
```

It returns this:

```
�PNG  IHDR,�ݽK�IDATx������H���r,����p�CU�.!$Aw�ZB�h�].��ˀAM��O�5��D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�D�~F_����������7�)D��̎�s�"��po;,^�2?@�o�?���Y�N��覺�n~RM'������~�{���s� ��w� ���Z�\.їQƹ᝞��&*ȍ�i�&��K��v��T�:>�����m�;K5.��}�u�#��T�W"�����nݫM����������K5���noOx�mr�Ǎpc~�;��GKq��䧽��R�8)���R��l��槽@Ok�;��#�_æ�s���h���p�@�%��bgv���1H��E�R���ZI����P~}�8�N"|T��:�(��N�T��8�G����Sx�oX=��P�#�l%�܄������k�Ò�P�\-�����b*�tX)B��z�e"T +JwX#B�T�D�@6*�a��K*v�=�{ d]�    I��V��%���d^�y#T G�0i� ��*&�Ƒ1Bk���X�#��@��??�"LxPљl3�.���1�K>E�"�vDѫT��+��0 �lVbV���N��I�3)����f�E�V;lR,e� E�.#�I��A��ua{�a�bJO���Y���gR�b��f�G8�bf��7%����?h�����l�gR'��F�p�%Ŧ�Sm| �8��ƍp�1Ŧ���~p��f�Gx���&� ^z����]����Rlj������o&�e��8��}oU��W"|b_��� w�GL{�D�����fy�m��['���Te��6h�m$�C� ��鉾�����O�� ��A�4����N��b�M��t"|��I-���>@��8ͩ��[FZ����YN"�K3�(���P�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!�!����z�gt8IEND�B`�
```

Comment: Is there any other code running? Try putting the header at the first line...

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos There's no other code running

Comment: That looks fine. Where are you trying to look at the image? In a browser?

Comment: So, try putting the header at the very first line...

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos If that was the problem, there would be a textual notice in the output.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes in a browser. I have a plain php file with the code showed above.

Comment: And there's nothing after `?>`? You can even remove that closing tag.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Nothing after the `?>`. Removing it doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: Just to be sure: which browser do you use to test this? Did you try other browsers as well?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel just if notices are enabled...

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos You're correct, but nothing is written before the image is output. If I test this code locally, everything works as expected.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I tried Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Which's your PHP version? Which OS?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Phpver is 5.4.4 and OS is Mac OSX 10.7.5

Comment: Ok, so, turn on error reporting:
`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');`
And see if there is some output

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos No output on that side. However, when I look into the Chrome developer tools, in Network it's says that the page is treated as text/html.

Comment: I'm running Arch Linux with PHP 5.5.5 with GD 2.1.0 and it's working just fine... Maybe is a problem with your version. Try upgrade it...

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Ha, another Arch Linux user here! :-)

Comment: @Wistar What is the exact output of dev tools? Perhaps Googling with with "png" might lead you to some other threads on this issue.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder What do you want exactly from the dev tools? I'm googling every possible combinations of png.

Comment: Did you already try `php file.php > file.png` and looked at the generated file?

Comment: Just tried it, the file cannot be opened "It might be damaged".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct header is`Content-Type` (note the capital t)

From the comments I see you figured out that the content type is replaced with text/plain. This is most likely something your webserver does. It probably sees .php and overrides the output. If you run your file from the command line (`php file.php > file.png`) and open the resulting file it probably renders fine.

Comment: I corrected my header on the code shown in the question accordingly but it does not change the outcomes

Comment: Just tried it, the file cannot be opened "It might be damaged".

Comment: That is kind of weird, but it might be working in your own user directory.

Comment: It works now! You were right. It was a problem with the Content-Type. For some reasons, my browser treated it as text even if there was a `header` in the code. I solved the problem by removing the header in the code and making a route to this file in which I specify the header with the `Content-Type image/png`.

Comment: Which webserver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try deleting the blank line between your variable defines and the beginning of your draw operations? It's probably causing PHP to flush the headers, so it can send the blank line as content, before you set the Content-Type header below it.

Either that, or even better, move the Header set up to the top of the script.

Comment: The OP uses the correct header, see the code. When I test this, I see a green ellipse.

Comment: If you read the comments to the question, you would've known that he tried Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error can occurred by empty lines after the PHP closing `?>`. Use a true plain text editor (e.g. *vi/vim*) to check it, or take a look on the hexdump of the file.